# Интерполяция с помощью scipy

Tags: python, математика, scipy

В целом задание звучит так:

Існує набір даних speed, який є значенням швидкості, для транспортного засобу в певній точці спостереження. Очевидно, що дані має дискретний вид. Відомо, що спостереження відбувалисьз періодом в одну годину.

```
speed = [25,35,45,30,60,120,100,100,70,75,80,65]
```

1. Скажімо, в нульовій координаті ми маємо швидкість 25 км / год, згідно з набором даних speed.Помістить у змінну time-вектор часу, створений за допомогоюnp.linspace(всього 12 спостережень, від 0 до 11 годин).
2. Виконайте вивід масиву часу time
3. Побудуйте графік точок швидкості(plot).Вкажіть розмір області відображення(0, 11)і(0, 130).Зробіть відображення сітки
4. Виконати інтерполяцію за допомогою interpld(kind='cubic') і отримати функцію з 10 000 значеннями. Створіть неперервний графік отриманої функції.

Вот мой код:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate, interpolate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#1
speed=[25, 35, 45, 30, 60, 120, 100, 100, 70, 75, 80, 65]
time = np.linspace(0, 11, num=12)

#2
print(time)

#3
speed_new = [25, 35, 45, 30, 60, 120, 100, 100, 70, 75, 80, 65]
new_time = np.linspace(0, 11, num=12)
!!!!! f = interpolate.interp1d(speed_new, new_time, kind='cubic')

plt.plot(time, speed, "o", speed_new, f(speed_new), "--")
plt.title("Графік швидкості")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

У меня ошибка с созданием функции, помогите понять что не так сделал пж)

```
raise ValueError("Expect x to not have duplicates")
ValueError: Expect x to not have duplicates
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну вам же английским языком написано - по оси `x` не должно быть дубликатов. У вас `x` - это `time`, а `y` - это `speed`. Параметры `interp1d` - `x` и `y`. А вы получается наоборот `y` вместо `x` передаёте и там есть повторяющиеся значения. Ну и используете вы полученную интерполяцией функцию тоже неправильно. Вам нужно сделать новый `x`, т.е. `time` и применить на нём эту функцию.

В общем, правильный код:

```
#3
speed = [25, 35, 45, 30, 60, 120, 100, 100, 70, 75, 80, 65]
time = np.linspace(0, 11, num=12)
f = interpolate.interp1d(time, speed, kind='cubic')
time_new = np.linspace(0, 11, num=10000)

plt.plot(time, speed, "o", time_new, f(time_new), "--")
plt.title("Графік швидкості")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]